# How can I get the child view index?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

If I have:

```
public class SectionView extends AbstractSectionView {
private final EditText nameET;

private final EditText valueET;

private final TextView tapHere;

public SectionView(Context c) {
    super(c);
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_section, this);
}
```

with layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/my_section"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/name"
        android:onClick="startNextScreen">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tapHereLabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="Next Screen" />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/value" ....
```

Multiple of these SectionViews are added as children to a fragment called MyFragment with this layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/section_views_container"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <!-- SectionViews added here by java code -->
    </LinearLayout>
```

I added the onClick listener to RelativeLayout "my_section", so I have this click handler in the fragment's Activity:

```
/* v is the RelativeLayout called my_section in the SectionView's     
 * layout
 */
public void startNextScreen(View v) {
    // SectionView root view
    RelativeLayout sectionView = (RelativeLayout)v.getParent();

    /* f is the fragment that holds a LinearLayout that has   
     * SectionView children added at runtime 
     */
    MyFragment f = (MyFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("MyFragment");
    LinearLayout sectionViewsContainer = (LinearLayout)f.getView().findViewById(R.id.section_views_container);

    for(int childIndex=0; childIndex < sectionViewsContainer.getChildCount(); childIndex++) {
        SectionView child = (SectionView)sectionViewsContainer.getChildAt(childIndex);

        if(child.equals(sectionView)) {
            tappedIndex = childIndex;
            break;
        }
     }
```

The equals comparison never resolves to true because I am comparing a SectionView type to a RelativeLayout type.  But the RelativeLayout is the root view, so isn't it also the SectionView?

Once one of the section views is clicked, how do I reference both it and the current child inside the loop with the same type?  Casting the clicked view "v" or the child view throws a ClassCastException.  AbstractSectionView extends from FrameLayout and I cannot change that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get child view for SectionView not getParent

Comment: I don't think so, the view that is clicked is RelativeLayout with id "my_section".  SectionViews are dynamically placed as children of a linearlayout of a fragment whose xml I have not posted.  So I want the whole SectionView, not a child.  How do I access the whole SectionView with only "my_section"?

Comment: need to check can you post your xml and class so that i can check the way you are adding and getting